# Not able to read session id from response in jmeter

Tags: performance, jmeter

i want to fetch "chat_session_id": 8216, from response data and apply regular expression extractor

"chat_session_id": (.+?)

but it only fetches 8 instead of 8216

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did correctly, the mistake is you need to add comma to your regular expression

```
Actual value: "chat_session_id": 8216,

Regx:         "chat_session_id": (.+?),
```

Answer (score 1):

Try amending your regular expression to look like:

```
"chat_session_id": (\d+)
```

This one will match any number following the `chat_session_id:` so it should work as it evidenced by [View Results Tree](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) listener output:

[image: View Results Tree - RegExp Tester]

---

In general, given you are getting the response in JSON format it would make more sense to use [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) which is designed for working with JSON data type. The relevant [JSON Path Expression](https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath) would be as simple as:

```
$..chat_session_id
```